# Exercise With arraylist input with scanner

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

my exercise is with collect soccer cards inside an arraylist.
inside my code I have to insert the methods: "`add, search, remove, print and modify`".
From input I must save all data of name of player, surname and country after that from output someone can ask me about player so i can tell it from code.
My problem is i can't add some thing from input and i don't know how to continue with another methods after input with `Scanner`.

MAIN:

```
package figurines;
import java.util.*;

public class Figurines {

    public  ArrayList<Giocatori> lista =  new ArrayList<Giocatori>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1 Penaldo 2 Pessi 3 Neymar 4 Buffon");
        
        Scanner searchBar = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserisci I dati del giocatore");
        String search = searchBar.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        for (Giocatori liste : lista) {  
            if (liste.getCognome().equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
                System.out.println(" Nome = " + liste.getNome() +" Paese= " + liste.getPaese());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CLASS WHERE I CAN ADD METHODS

```
package figurines;
import java.util.*;

public class Gestione {
    
    public void input(){
        ArrayList<Giocatori> list = new ArrayList<Giocatori>();
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserisci il nome del giocatore: ");
        String name;
        String surname;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter first name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter last name: ");
        surname = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

SOME ARRAY METHODS:

```
package figurines;
import java.util.*;

public class Giocatori {
    
    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private String paese;

    public Giocatori(String nome, String cognome, String paese) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.paese = paese;
    }
    

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public String getPaese() {
        return paese;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific question or state a specific problem where exactly you are stuck with this task. I recommend you edit your question and specify what your problem is because without that people will interpret your question as simply expecting us to do the complete assignment for you, which will only attract downvotes.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS done i just asked how can i comtinue cause i'm stucked with input of player inside arraylist

Comment: First of all, your implementation is just plain wrong, why would you have `ArrayList` of `Players` in your `Figures` class? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AP11 that was just a try cause the code wasn't running so tried to put there idk why

Comment: I'm not being snarky, but I strong suggest that you don't put code anywhere unless you know why you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your classes `Gestione` and `Figurines` don't make much sense. Why would you have `List` of players in your `Figurines` class? These are basics and you should know, how to make `classes` and `functions`.

This is my recommended implementation of `Gestione` class:

```
public class Gestione {

    private List<Giocatori> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Giocatori giocatori) {
        list.add(giocatori);
    }

    public Giocatori search(String cognome) {
        // search by surname
        for (Giocatori g : list) {
            if (g.getCognome().equals(cognome)) return g;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void remove(Giocatori giocatori) {
        list.remove(giocatori);
    }

    public void print() {
        for (Giocatori g : list) {
            System.out.println(g);
            // create toString method in Giocatori
        }
    }

    public void modify() {
        // I don't know what modify should do
    }

    public List<Giocatori> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: From input i have to insert players name surname and country so that must be saved into arraylist. the command of excerise is Realize in Java, a program that simulates a collection
 of soccer cards, a minimum of three attributes of your choice is required
and the use of the functionalities of the dynamic arrays LinkedList or ArrayList.
The program should have the methods: "add, search, remove, print and modify". @AP11

Comment: But it's your homework, so I gave you template and explanation of why you should do things differently, the rest is all on you.